# How to bookmark various spots in a video using C#

Tags: c#

I need to bookmark various places in a video.Save these bookmarks,which user can use again to go to that section of video.
How can I achieve this?
thanks

Comment: You need to be way, way, WAY more specific.

Comment: Please be more specific in your question.

Comment: How is the user looking at the video in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

[Annodex](http://www.annodex.net/) videos allow you to link to particular points in Ogg Theora videos. You can then seek directly to the point in question.

The Annodex libraries are written in C, so you would be able to call them from C#.